# keys unspecified in the SSH config file are being attempted by ssh client

Tags: ssh

I have edited my ~/.ssh/config file, removing some obsolete `Host` definitions from it, however when I ssh to a remote server (using the `-v` option for verbose output), I still see the old `Host` definitions being attempted.

Do I need to run a certain command to make the have SSH reload the config file, in order for the changes to take effect?

This an Ubuntu Desktop using the default ssh, no fancy configuration, although the machine has upgraded between several older versions of Ubuntu to get to 16.04. The last upgrade was long ago, it is not an upgrade issue, just comes up now that I try to add a new key to the ~/.ssh/config and clean it up.

Comment: What exactly do the attempts look like? they should indicate which file the definitions are being read from e.g. `/home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for somehost`

Comment: Thanks, the output shows the config file used is indeed the one I've edited. Maybe it's the default for SSH to try all keys present under ~/ssh if the specified authentication keys fail.

Comment: OK I don't think you mentioned "keys" in the original version of your question: if keys are the issue, perhaps the problem is that they have been cached in a keyring or ssh-agent (rather than being read from file)?

Comment: Could well be. Can't say I really recall how ssh-agent should affect using ssh, how it plugs into the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also clean up `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, as it might contain some of those `Hosts` you see when `ssh`-ing somewhere.

When using the `ssh` client, command-line options take precedence over configuration files. The user-specific configuration file `~/.ssh/config` is used next. Finally, the global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file is used. The first obtained value for each configuration parameter will be used.

Comment: They are not present at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, but it looks like SSH is just grabbing all keys it can find under ~/.ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many keys in your `~/.ssh` directory, AND the ssh server you're attempting to connect to has `#MaxAuthTries` set to default the default of `6`, you will get this error:

```
Received disconnect from 10.20.30.40 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 10.20.30.40 port 22
```

It would be too involved to set all of your potentially hundreds/thousands of OpenSSH servers config files to allow for an increased number of `MaxAuthTries`. It'd also be a security risk too.

The solution I came to was to store all ssh keys in a non-default location. Your `~/.ssh/config` entries then look like this, pointing to the correct location of the IdentityFile

```
Host jenkins
    User root
    HostName 10.0.0.29
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/wayne/keys/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this is one of the first search results I tried.  Based on my later success from other answers, I suggest using `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your config:

```
Host jenkins
    User root
    HostName 10.0.0.29
    Port 22
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile /home/wayne/keys/jenkins
```

For more discussion, see Flimm's answer about this option at https://superuser.com/a/268777/58805

Comment: I see even more context on this option in chrishiestand's answer to the same question at https://superuser.com/a/436015/58805.